# Why the pixmap(a football field image) disappear when I try to draw something on its QLabel?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter, qpixmap

guys.I have a QLabel with a pixmap-a PNG image(typically a football playground) and I wanna draw some rectangels(represent some robots)  on the playground,which I use the painter class to draw actually on its container-the QLabel. But when I use the painter to draw the REC,the RECT showed but the image just turned to blank.I don't know why it failed, and could u plz do me a favor and give me some hints on that?

```
class FieldLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    positionData = {"1":{"x":13,"y":20},"2":{"x":28,"y":19},"3":{"x":17,"y":21}}
    def __init__(self, image_path):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self)
        self.field = QtGui.QPixmap("field.png")
        self.setPixmap(self.field.scaled(self.size(),
                                         QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                           QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)


    def paintEvent(self,e):
        draw = QtGui.QPainter()
        draw.begin(self)
        draw.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        draw.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        draw.drawRect(0,0,10,10)
        draw.end()
```

Answer (score 1):

`paintEvent` is responsible for drawing everything in the widget. Since you're overriding it, `QLabel`'s default implementation, which draws the `QPixmap`, is not invoked.

So, first you should let the `QLabel` do its painting, then you can paint over it as you like:

```
def paintEvent(self,e):
    # call the base implementation to paint normal interface
    super(FieldLabel, self).paintEvent(e)

    # then paint over it
    draw = QtGui.QPainter()
    draw.begin(self)
    draw.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
    draw.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
    draw.drawRect(0,0,10,10)
    draw.end()
```

Comment: Thank u.@Avaris That's very helpful.I didn't recognize the set of pixmap is  also a paintEvent and will have some override effect.

Comment: And I'm also working on some coordinate system on that Label and pixmap.But I was suprised to find that when I got and print out some height and width integer values(using predefined methods like `.height()`and`.width()`) from the Label and the Pixmap, the values of the Pixmap is even larger than the Label's.So I guess the two classes use different measure unit mathematically.So how can I get the same measure background so I can calculate some coordinates for my paintings?

Comment: @Derek: Not they have the same unit (pixels). But you're putting the pixmap scaled to the size of `QLabel`. If you don't do any scaling or manually setting the size of label, `QLabel` will adjust itself to the size of the pixmap.

Comment: yeah,I found you are absolutely right.I use the methods and they all return some fixed values even when the pixmap is scaled.So is there a way to get the current size value of the pixmap? I tried with some caculations by label values minus margin and intent,but that two are also fixed with 0 and -1.(It's so painful to try to paint  on the flexible monitor label.)

Comment: @Derek: Just load your pixmap and its `.size()` will be the correct dimensions.

Comment: I would rather say to load the scaled pixmap for precision, cuz I didn't explicitly define a QPixmap object for the scaled pixmap like `scaled_Pixmap=self.field.scaled(self.width(),self.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)`.LoL, finally I can find a fix myself,thank your so much.